# How to fix an input or a select at the bottom of a tr tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a form inside a table: each `<td>` tag contains either a `<select>` or an `<input>`, but for example in this case, since the value of the first `<td>`'s label is longer than the one on the second one, the `<input>` or `<select>` fields are not in the same line (please see picture).

[image: fields are not in the same line]

```
<tr>        
    <td>
        <div class="form-group select optional personal_conflict_victim">
            <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_conflict_victim">¿USTED ES VÍCTIMA DEL CONFLICTO ARMADO Y SE ENCUENTRA INCLUIDO EN EL REGISTRO ÚNICO DE VÍCTIMAS?</label>
            <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[conflict_victim]" id="personal_conflict_victim"><option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                <option value="true">Si</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group select optional personal_victimizing_fact">
            <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_victimizing_fact">¿CUÁL ES EL HECHO VICTIMIZANTE?</label>
            <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[victimizing_fact]" id="personal_victimizing_fact">
                <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                <option value="Desaparición forzada">Desaparición forzada</option>
                <option value="Secuestro">Secuestro</option>
                <option value="Reclutamiento forzado y utilización">Reclutamiento forzado y utilización</option>
                <option value="Desplazamiento">Desplazamiento</option>
                <option value="Homicidio">Homicidio</option>
                <option value="Masacre">Masacre</option>
                <option value="Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE">Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE</option>
                <option value="Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes">Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes</option>
                <option value="Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)">Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)</option>
                <option value="Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual">Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual</option>
                <option value="Despojo">Despojo</option>
                <option value="Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal">Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>           
</tr>
```

So, how can i make my two fields stick to the bottom of the  parent element, keeping them in the same line no matter how many lines the labels occupy ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please provide CSS for this code first.

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski it only uses bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `vertical-align` css property and set `baseline` or `bottom`.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group select optional personal_conflict_victim">
        <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_conflict_victim">¿USTED ES VÍCTIMA DEL CONFLICTO ARMADO Y SE ENCUENTRA INCLUIDO EN EL REGISTRO ÚNICO DE VÍCTIMAS?</label>
        <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[conflict_victim]" id="personal_conflict_victim"><option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                <option value="true">Si</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group select optional personal_victimizing_fact">
        <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_victimizing_fact">¿CUÁL ES EL HECHO VICTIMIZANTE?</label>
        <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[victimizing_fact]" id="personal_victimizing_fact">
                <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                <option value="Desaparición forzada">Desaparición forzada</option>
                <option value="Secuestro">Secuestro</option>
                <option value="Reclutamiento forzado y utilización">Reclutamiento forzado y utilización</option>
                <option value="Desplazamiento">Desplazamiento</option>
                <option value="Homicidio">Homicidio</option>
                <option value="Masacre">Masacre</option>
                <option value="Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE">Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE</option>
                <option value="Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes">Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes</option>
                <option value="Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)">Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)</option>
                <option value="Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual">Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual</option>
                <option value="Despojo">Despojo</option>
                <option value="Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal">Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## OR

If you want to align also the labels try this one:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
label {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
select {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group select optional personal_conflict_victim">
            <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_conflict_victim">¿USTED ES VÍCTIMA DEL CONFLICTO ARMADO Y SE ENCUENTRA INCLUIDO EN EL REGISTRO ÚNICO DE VÍCTIMAS?</label>
            <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[conflict_victim]" id="personal_conflict_victim"><option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                    <option value="true">Si</option>
                    <option value="false">No</option>
                </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group select optional personal_victimizing_fact">
            <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_victimizing_fact">¿CUÁL ES EL HECHO VICTIMIZANTE?</label>
            <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[victimizing_fact]" id="personal_victimizing_fact">
                    <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                    <option value="Desaparición forzada">Desaparición forzada</option>
                    <option value="Secuestro">Secuestro</option>
                    <option value="Reclutamiento forzado y utilización">Reclutamiento forzado y utilización</option>
                    <option value="Desplazamiento">Desplazamiento</option>
                    <option value="Homicidio">Homicidio</option>
                    <option value="Masacre">Masacre</option>
                    <option value="Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE">Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE</option>
                    <option value="Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes">Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes</option>
                    <option value="Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)">Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)</option>
                    <option value="Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual">Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual</option>
                    <option value="Despojo">Despojo</option>
                    <option value="Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal">Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal</option>
                </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: But i want  to keep the label aligned as well.

Comment: @SebastianDelgado I updated the answer with the 2nd variant. Hope it helps. I am using bare tag selectors here, but its better to have custom classes to specify css behavior on top bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the `<select>` element at the bottom of the cell, though it requires a minimum height set for the table cell's contents.

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

td div.select {
  min-height: 150px;
}

td select {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group select optional personal_conflict_victim">
        <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_conflict_victim">¿USTED ES VÍCTIMA DEL CONFLICTO ARMADO Y SE ENCUENTRA INCLUIDO EN EL REGISTRO ÚNICO DE VÍCTIMAS?</label>
        <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[conflict_victim]" id="personal_conflict_victim"><option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                <option value="true">Si</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group select optional personal_victimizing_fact">
        <label class="control-label select optional" for="personal_victimizing_fact">¿CUÁL ES EL HECHO VICTIMIZANTE?</label>
        <select class="form-control select optional" name="personal[victimizing_fact]" id="personal_victimizing_fact">
                <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                <option value="Desaparición forzada">Desaparición forzada</option>
                <option value="Secuestro">Secuestro</option>
                <option value="Reclutamiento forzado y utilización">Reclutamiento forzado y utilización</option>
                <option value="Desplazamiento">Desplazamiento</option>
                <option value="Homicidio">Homicidio</option>
                <option value="Masacre">Masacre</option>
                <option value="Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE">Minas antipersona - Munición sin explotar MAP-MUSE</option>
                <option value="Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes">Tortura o tratos crueles, inhumanos o degradantes</option>
                <option value="Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)">Lesiones personales (permanentes o transitorias)</option>
                <option value="Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual">Delitos contra la integridad y libertad sexual</option>
                <option value="Despojo">Despojo</option>
                <option value="Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal">Daño en bienes muebles o inmuebles (terrorismo)- Amenaza a la vida, integridad y seguridad personal</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```